# class not found in doctrine2 entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have extended my doctrine2 entity:

```
namespace Hql\BaseBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

class Action extends _Entity
{
}
```

And I have created a file _Entity.php in the same folder:

```
namespace Hql\BaseBundle\Entity;

class _Entity 
{
}
```

It was my understanding that the class _Entity would be found automatically since it's in the same folder and the same namespace.

It didn't change any configuration file of Symfony2.

When I run the command `php app/console doctrine:mapping:info`, Symfony2 returns this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Hql\BaseBundle\Entity\_Entity' not found in [...]\Symfony\src\Hql\BaseBundle\Entity\Action.php on line 13
```

I have no idea how to correct this. Since the entity files are loaded automatically by the command, I don't know where to `include` my _Entity file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [PSR-0](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md) an underscore means a directory seperator so in the autoload function symfony is replacing the underscore with a directory separator.

So simply renaming `_Entity` to `Entity` will fix the issue